# PyCharm: break on built in function (such as `print`)?

Tags: python, pycharm, breakpoints, built-in

How can I make PyCharm break on built in function, such as `print`?
I've jumped to `print`'s "Declaration" with Ctrl-B, and got to a PyCharm stub file: `C:\Users\Zvika\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2022.1\python_stubs\-185531349\builtins.py`

Which has:

```
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None): # known special case of print
    # I've omitted the docstring
    pass
```

But it's not very useful, as PyCharm cannot put breakpoints on `pass`.

Any idea how can I break on `print`?

Comment: Note: that is not the code it will be executed, it is just a *python_stub* (the function is written n C). So you cannot put a break point. Just redefine `print` in your code and put there the break point

Comment: Also the stub you provide is invalid. `print` supports at least `flush` kwarg which is not mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this for debugging only, then the following will work:

```py
import builtins

def my_breakpoint(*args, **kwargs):  # Ingore arguments
    breakpoint()

# Redefine `print` builtin
builtins.print = my_breakpoint

print('foo')
# Drops into pdb
```

And `python_stubs` are only **stubs**, they provide information about argument and return types of functions. They have nothing to do with the real implementation (which is in C, of course).